# [].__proto__ === Array.prototype // === [Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): Object]?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototype, ecmascript-6

Defining a utility function to inspect objects' prototype chains (in Chrome), I get this for arrays.

[image: array prototype chain]

So it would appear that

```
[].__proto__ === Array.prototype  // === [Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): Object]
```

I understand the first equality. I have no idea what the third term is, though I have heard that ES6 will have Symbols.

Is this thing the same as Array.prototype? Why does it print that way?

Edit: chrome://version information:

```
Google Chrome   40.0.2214.111 (Official Build) 
Revision    6f7d3278c39ba2de437c55ae7e380c6b3641e94e-refs/branch-heads/2214@{#480}
OS  Linux 
Blink   537.36 (@189455)
JavaScript  V8 3.30.33.16
```

Comment: A minimum example would be `console.log([].__proto__)` which tells you that the browser you're using, which is probably Chrome, now defines `Array.__proto__` with the new Symbol type internally.

Comment: True. I missed that because I just inputed `[].__proto__` which prints as []. I gues the console doesn't console.log its results.

Comment: On that note, it is weird that entering `{}` into the console prints `undefined` and entering `{x: 3}` outputs `3`.

Comment: Take a look at the code review here: https://codereview.chromium.org/455743002, especially this one https://codereview.chromium.org/455743002/patch/1/10003

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? This looks like a dev snapshot :-)

Comment: No dev version. I've updated the question with the info.

Comment: "an object whose properties are the names of object properties that should not be included in a with statement"

Comment: What is that quote refering to? Where is it from?

Comment: Looks like he was quoting a book - https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read/ (see unscopeables), but you can see it in the draft standard as well: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-well-known-symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment on 2014-04-14

It seems Chrome's `console.log` print all Symbol-type-keys, here is an example:

```
var o = {};
o[Symbol.iterator] = function () {};
o[Symbol.unscopables] = {};
var s = Symbol('s');
o[s] = 3;
console.log(o);
```

which prints:

> Object {Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): Object, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): function, Symbol(s): 3}

I don't why chrome behaves this way, is it for debugging or something else?

Fotunately it does not affect the `toString()` result so all code is safe.

---

It seems `console.log` would especially print the `Symbol.unscopable` key in console, we can have a plain object to perform like this:

```
var o = {};
o[Symbol.unscopables] = {};
console.log(o);
```

which outputs:

> Object {Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): Object}

The `Symbol.unscopables` symbol is a special symbol defined in ES6 as `@@unscopables` which is used for excluding some properties when this object works in a `with` environment, the official explanation is:

> An object valued property whose own property names are property names that are excluded from the with environment bindings of the associated object.

A simple example:

```
var o = {x: 1, y: 2};
o[Symbol.unscopables] = {
    y: true
};

console.log(o.x); // 1
console.log(o.y); // 2

with(o) {
    console.log(x); // 1
    console.log(y); // ReferenceError: y is not defined
}
```

You can use `Array.prototype[Symbol.unscopables]` to find all keys which cannot be used in `with` environment

However still, the output of a `Array.prototype` is not exactly the same as a plain object with `Symbol.unscopables` key, it outputs `[Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): Object]`, which is a format more like an array

I can't exactly explain why, this may be related to the `Symbol.toStringTag` which controls how an object should be formatted to string, but Chrome currently does not export this symbol so it's hard to test